# uri to bitmap conversion fails

Tags: android, bitmap, firebase-storage, uri

I need to convert the uri to bitmap to set it as icon inside my notification.
To be sure to have a valid URI I use getdownloadurl, it works, If I print the uri it gives me the right link that works, anyway the try/catch always go inside the catch, can't really get why the try fails, I tried others conversion function and all fails, where I'm failing?

```
    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
    try {
       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
          bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
       } else {
          ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
          bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    
    }
```

Error:

```
2022-12-04 00:00:02.361 26634-26634/com.example.rememberme E/error: No content provider: https://firebasestorage.googlea... (the entire uri)
```

Comment: In your `catch`, log your exception to Logcat, then examine Logcat's output to see what the stack trace is: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: ok from that question I got that I can't do what I was doing, solved using getbytes and getting bitmap from the bytes, thanks